# Not a Group By Expression, with own declared functions

Tags: oracle, function, group-by

Ok so I know when using aggregate functions such as MAX, MIN, AVG and so fort, in a select statement. You need to use the GROUP BY function for all the selected columns that DON'T use the aggregate functions.EX

```
SELECT name, MAX(age)
FROM person
GROUP BY name
```

but my issue is, when I use my own functions for certain columns and I use an Aggregate function within my select statement. EX

```
SELECT f_fullname(name, surname) as fullname, max(age)
FROM person
```

Should i add the whole function as a part of the group by clause?

```
GROUP BY f_fullname(name, surname)
```

because at this moment i get the ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression error.

Thanks for your help!

PS. the select statements are just for explanation purposes**

Comment: :you need to add name and surname in group by clause,no need to add the function in group by

Comment: what happened when you tried it? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have the whole function or the columns which are the parameters.

```
select f_fullname(name , surname) full_name, max (age)
  from person
group by name, surname;
```

or

```
select f_fullname(name , surname) full_name, max (age)
  from person
group by f_fullname(name , surname);
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe498/1)

Comment: In the second case make sure you define `f_fullname` as deterministic.